# ggplot multicolomn on R using csv

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot my `.csv` data (I named it p) on R using ggplot2 but I am having difficulties.

```
Time d d d d c m m m m c c c...........   (top row of data p)
```

there are 14 rows and there are 304 columns. First column is time and rest are d c m so on ......I want to plot Time on x axis against rest 303 on y axis on a  single plot window  and these 303 graph lines to be distinguished by Color.

the top row  has letters like d c m.. theese are my 3 forest Groups: coniferous, deciduous, mixed. so i want all graph lines with 'd' to be grouped in one particular Color. then 'c' in another Color and 'm' in some other.

I found a way to do that using ggplot

```
ggplot(p, aes(x = Time, group = 1)) +
geom_line(aes(y = d), colour="blue") +
geom_line(aes(y = c), colour = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y = m), colour = "green") +
ylab(label="NDVI") + xlab("Time")
```

but from 303 i have 117 columns of d
77 for c
109 for m

What code should I use so R would plot all columns by giving all ds , cs and ms different Color?

Please help I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: I am not clear how your data looks, but you can try to convert your data from wide format to long. That will make plotting easier for you. Here look at a few examples for the conversion- http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7439/38261

Comment: oh i mentioned rows coloums opposite in my question

Comment: i have 14 rows ....304 coloumns

Comment: first coloumn is time and then rest are my forest types   and under forest type (d c m) i have ndvi values.....so basically this d c m are my coloumn headings.... i hope you can imagine now how my file Looks like

Comment: i have made my data like this on purpose ...is there a way i can use it as it is without converting to Long format

Comment: what is the difference between the various `c` columns ? are they all named `c` ? you can post `dput` output of a subset of the full dataset. Also you can edit your original post instead of putting in comments, because I'm unable to understand what do you mean by `14 coloumns and there are 304 coloumns`.

Comment: thank you i have edited my post.... yes the various c coloumns are all named c.... similarly ist for d and m...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition I hope will suit your needs:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

time <- 1:14 # your 14 rows
# here data with only 3 forest types, consider using yours instead !
data.test <- data.frame(time=time, d=runif(14, max=1)*time, c=runif(14, max=2)*time, m=runif(14, max=3)*time)

#reshape your data for it to suit the ggploting
data.test <- melt(data.test, id.vars="time", variable.name="forest", value.name="y")

# add a numeric version of the factor forest (for gradient color)
data.test$numeric.forest <- rep(1:3, each=14) # replace 1:3 by 1:304

# first plot, each forest type got a color ... should not be readable with your dimensions (304 lines)
ggplot(data.test) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y, group=forest, color=forest))

# if you have 304 forest types, you might consider using color gradient, 
# but you need to identify a logical order in your forest, for the gradient to be informative ...
ggplot(data.test) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y, group=forest, color=numeric.forest), alpha=.9)
# consider playing with alpha (transparency) for your lines to be readable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your Kind help. I am new to r so I have to struggle a bit to get things done. I tried your method but after #  add a numeric version of the factor forest (for gradient color)
 it gives error

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "numeric.forest", value = c(1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 4256 rows, data has 42          so now i am stuck i am not sure what this means

Comment: This hapened just because you have used this line :
    `data.test <- data.frame(time=time, d=runif(14, max=1)*time, c=runif(14, max=2)*time, m=runif(14, max=3)*time)`
which is 42 rows long instead of your data, which should be 4256 rows long (304 * 14). I put this line juste to generate random data to have plots to display but you need to adapt it to your dimensions ! You might juste need a `read.table("path/to/your/data.csv")` or `read.csv("path/to/your/data.csv")` instead ! Sorry for the delay in my reponse, big AFK time...

Comment: oh i see...  thank you so much...in the meantime i also found another way of doing it and finally got it.first i Change the way my data Looks like i transposed rows and coloumns and then i used simple plot function like this

Comment: p <- read.csv ("NDVI_plot_final2.csv")

p <- read.table("NDVI_plot_final2.csv", dec = ".", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

names(p)

s <- seq(1,15,1)

levels(p$Forest_type)[levels(p$Forest_type)=="d"] <- "red"
levels(p$Forest_type)[levels(p$Forest_type)=="m"] <- "green"
levels(p$Forest_type)[levels(p$Forest_type)=="c"] <- "blue"


plot (s , p[1,2:16], col = as.character (p$Forest_type [1]), ylim = c(-0.1,1)) 

lines(s, p[1,2:16], col = as.character(p$Forest_type[1])) 

for (i in 2:nrow(Rvals)){
  par(new=FALSE)
  lines(s, p[i,2:16], col = as.character(p$Forest_type[i]) )
}